# Running a function after a fixed time interval in PHP?

Tags: php, service

Hi I need one of my php function to be executed again & again after fixed interval of time. Please point me to APIs in PHP which are capable of doing so. Thanks.

Comment: May be you are looking for `cronjob`

Comment: Use `crontab` to run the script periodically.

Comment: check out `cron tutorial php` on `google` and you will find code and video tutorial as well

Comment: @Anant & Barmar thanks for your info looking for tutorials

Comment: Here is a question on SO with some information on running a php file using cronjob. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: @pcj  because its too broad concept and varies based on requirement. So it's not possible to give any code right here.

Comment: @LockeDonohoe  that question have no correct answer. So i don't think any of the solution is fully working. Also very less explanation is given. But let OP have to look to that too. May be he will get something useful from them

Comment: @Anant it was my impression that it had no **accepted** answer, not necessarily no **correct** answer.

Comment: @Anant I was searching for what api to search hence no problem, I will figure out the usage of cronjob or crontab :)

Comment: @LockeDonohoe yes you are right. That's why i said let OP have a look to that too also